# How to make a column range dynamic using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic, range

I am using the followig code to convert decimals into %.
The number of datapoints in column B will change daily. How can I make the range dynamic so that the code works?

```
For Each c In [B2:B47]
    If c.Value < 1 Then
        c.Value = c.Value * 100
    End If
    c.NumberFormat = "0.00\%"
Next c
```

Thank you.

Comment: `Range("B2:B47")` where you construct the inner address string as needed

Comment: Hi! In your suggestion the range is limited to B47. Please let me know if I did not understand your advice correctly.I am trying to make it dynamic because number of datapoints in column B will change daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use a while loop for this task. The loop goes until it reaches a blank cell (i.e. the end of the data)

```
Sub ranges()

Dim c As Range
Dim n As Integer
n = 2

While Sheets("sheetname").Cells(n, 2) <> ""
    
    Set c = Sheets("sheetname").Cells(n, 2)
    
    If c.Value < 1 Then
        c.Value = c.Value * 100
    End If
        c.NumberFormat = "0.00\%"
n = n + 1
Wend

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I tried this technique, as well. And, it works well!

Answer (score 0):

One method is to determine the first and last rows of the range.

Frequently, the first row is known and hard-coded; the last row can be found by starting at the bottom and moving up.

for example

```
    'should always declare your variables
    Dim r As Range, c As Range
    
    'should always fully qualify the reference
    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheet4")
        Set r = Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp))
    End With
    
        For Each c In r
            'do your thing
        Next c
```